# E possível fazer um CRUD básico em arquivo JSON?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json

Tenho o seguinte cenário.

Tenho um site de notícias em `ASP.NET MVC` que atualmente ao acessa-lo, todas as informações são pegas no banco. Quero tirar essas requisições do Front.

Pensei em fazer um arquivo `Data.json` e toda vez que uma notícia fosse cadastrada salvaria no banco e no arquivo mediante a necessidade.

Ex: Toda vez que o site e aberto vou ao banco e busco as 5 ultimas notícias sobre Política e  Esportes, como já sei quantas notícias de cada editoria preciso para apresentar no FrontEnd, criaria somente o necessário no arquivo.

Mas como não e um banco, quando precisar "Desativar" um notícia por exemplo, teria que ir no arquivo, remover aquela notícia e colocar uma outra para não quebrar o esquema do FrontEnd.

E viável fazer um CRUD para fazer essas operações no arquivo JSON? Alguém conhece um esquema melhor para se chegar a este ponto?

Comment: Você quer algo assim? https://github.com/typicode/lowdb

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez Exatamente isto, mas confesso que não faço a mínima ideia de como implementar o LowDb com o Asp.NET MVC.

Comment: Eu também não sei usar. Vou ter que dar uma estudada pra te responder.

Comment: Sem problemas! Estou pesquisando também!!

Answer (score 1):

Apesar do custo computacional, uma opção para este caso, poderia ser, trabalhar diretamente na serialização e deserialização de instâncias de classes que materializassem JSON via métodos. O trabalho de CRUD seria em instâncias de classes e não em arquivos que poderiam gerar um fluxo indesejado de I/O. Poderia ter uma tarefa de background para garantir a serialização do fluxo de dados em memória para  arquivo físico.